# I am creating a Discord bot, and there was a need to create slash commands. Several commands work, but all the others give a TypeError

Tags: python, discord.py

````
@slash.slash(name='info', description='information',
             options=[{"name": "category", "description": "category info", "type": 3, "required": True}])
@bot.command()
async def info(ctx, categoty: str = None):
    print(categoty)
    match categoty:
        case 'commands':
            await ctx.send(f"```{categoty}:\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}hello\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}top\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}avatar\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}balance\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}reward\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}take```")
        case 'help':
            await ctx.send("```information```")
        case None:
            await ctx.send(f"```info:\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}info commands\
            \n    {setting['prefix']}info help```")
        case _:
            await ctx.send("```commands not found```")
````

The function itself works fine if it is called through a prefix, but if through a slash, it gives this error.

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `info`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bogdan/PycharmProjects/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/Users/bogdan/PycharmProjects/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 210, in invoke
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/bogdan/PycharmProjects/discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 374, in __call__
    return await self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: info() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'
```

Comment: Please post the code and an error as text not image.

Comment: I did as you asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve misspelt category, and in slash command options you have the correct spelling - so the code is providing the wrong keyword argument.